# Collapse table column while using min-width

Tags: html, css

I have a table and a column in it which contains text, that should be readable

So I set css like `min-width: 32em; max-width: 40em;`. But overall table is very wide so I try to save as much space as I can, and I wanna to collapse column if text width is smaller than `min-width`

But `min-width` is minimum width, so even if all this column cells are empty, it occupies space

I also cannot disable wrapping

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Mayby not to specify `min-width` at all? Why do you need it?

Comment: You would still get some spacing if you dont call `padding = 0;` on your `<td>`'s. You would get the best output using media queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for example

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 300px) {
#Table
{
 display: none;
}
}
```